# Parse a PGM image file into a struct containing ints and an array - how to implement a struct?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I want to make a struct that contains 2 integers and one array, however, size of the array is determined by  the 2 integers of the struct.  (array size= first integer times second integer)

In our code we need to open and read a .txt file to get the first 2 integers and initialize them.

How can I make such a struct in MARS?

> [image]

Comment: Are the integers stored in the file as binary words, or as ASCII strings of digits?  If the former, you can just read the file into a big buffer and treat is as a struct.  (You don't need any special syntax, just use offsets in your addressing modes.)  Otherwise read and parse the integers, then read the rest of the file into the buffer starting at an 8 byte offset.

Comment: Are you sure you need a single struct of this form with sizes and embedded array?  It looks to me more like a description of the file format, where you only need independent variables rather than a single aggregate.  (None the less, a struct can be had by simply combining the required storage for the sizes and the array, if that's what you really need.  There's no special code for creating a struct, we just use appropriate offsets to access fields.)

Comment: @PeterCordes  i added a screen shot of the question ,

Comment: Don't post pictures of text.  Copy/paste it.  But anyway, remember in asm, you don't need to use special syntax to organize data in memory; you can treat a flat block of memory (reserved with `.space` or dynamically allocated) as a struct just by storing the right data to the right places.

Comment: Oh, so you have to support reading a text or binary `.pgm`.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#File_formats.  So yes, you have to parse integers from strings before you do a malloc, and possibly in the main loop, too.  But I guess you don't need to support a maxval > 255, because uint8_t is only 1 byte.

Comment: @MatinTahmasebpour I think this is already answered here ("Creating struct in MARS/MIPS") - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242653/mars-mips-and-struct-nodes

Perhaps this should help :)